# Regex for json in mysql field

Tags: mysql, regex, json

I have a survey-field containing JSON data like this:

```
{
    "reason":
    {
        "0":"first",
        "1":"second",
        "other":["on","third"]
    },
    "comment":"fourth"
}
```

I want to select the first,second,third and fourth values in SQL.

Thank you.

Comment: use `$result=json_decode($array,true); print_r($result);`

Comment: I think we misunderstood each other. I want to do it only in SQL.

Comment: is the structure same always?

Comment: Yes, it is always like this. Only there can be 2,3,4... but it always starts with 0 and there is always an other and a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
var JSONObject = {"reason":{"0":"first","1":"second","other":["on","third"]},"comment":"fourth"};

document.getElementById("first").innerHTML=JSONObject.reason[0];

document.getElementById("second").innerHTML= JSONObject.reason[1];

document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML= JSONObject.comment[0];
```